# XOR Matrix Multiplication in Python

Tags: python, matrix-multiplication, xor

I am not sure how to multiply two matrices using the XOR addition. For example, here:

```
>>> b = numpy.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                     [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                     [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]])
>>> z = numpy.array([1, 1, 0, 1])
>>> z.dot(b)
array([1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
```

I would like the 4th, 5th, and 6th indices of the resulting array to be computed by:

```
1(1) xor 0(1) xor 1(0) xor 1(1) = 0
1(1) xor 1(1) xor 1(0) xor 0(1) = 0
0(1) xor 1(1) xor 1(0) xor 1(1) = 0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: How about `z.dot(b) % 2`?

Comment: I think that should work, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I commented, you can use `z.dot(b) % 2` to get the values you want. This is because chained `xor`s are equivalent to addition mod 2. That is, the result will be `1` if the number of `1`s was odd, and `0` if it was even.